# Why does my code ask for "Please enter a number between 2-12: " twice?

Tags: c++

Why does my code ask for `"Please enter a number between 2-12: "` twice?
When I run the program it prompts the user twice to enter `"Please enter a number between 2-12: "`.

This is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
//This program prompts the user to select a number between 2 and 12
//computer throws two dices
//player win if selected number matches the sum of the two dices thrown by computer
//for this Wednesday complete program by:
//add a module/function that throws first dice
//add a module/function that throws second dice
//add a function that evaluate game (comparing user selection with sum of the two dices)
//display outcome
//prompt the user if he/she wants to play again or quit
using namespace std;


int user();
int throwdice();
int Evaluate();

int main()
{
    int userchoice = 0;
    int Dice = 0;
    int Display = 0;
    do
    {
        userchoice = user();
        Dice = throwdice();
        Display = Evaluate();
    }
    while (Display == 1);

}

int user()
{
    int usernumber = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a number between 2-12: ";

while (true)
        {
            cin >> usernumber;
            if (usernumber < 2 || usernumber > 12)
                {
                cout << "Error! \n";
                cout << "Please enter a number between 2-12: ";
                }
                else
                    break;
        }

return usernumber;
}

int throwdice()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int Dice = 0;
    int Dice2 = 0;

    srand(time(0));
    Dice = rand()%6+1;
    Dice2 = rand()%6+1;
    sum = Dice + Dice2;
    return sum;
}

int Evaluate()
{
    int Dice = throwdice();
    int userchoice = user();
    int playagain = 0;

    cout << "You entered: " << userchoice << endl << "The computer has: " << Dice << endl;
    if (userchoice == Dice)
        cout << "YOU WIN!!!!";
        else
        {
            cout << "You lose.";
        }
    cout << "\nWanna play again? 1 for yes, anything else equals no.: ";
    cin >> playagain;
    if (playagain == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        cout << "Goodbye!";

}







/*
string display()
{
    string choice ("Y");
    int number = 0;
    number = user();

    if (number != Dice)
        cout << "You entered:\n " << number << "\nComputer entered\n" << Dice << "Try again?";
            else
                cout << "YOU WIN!!!!!!!!!!!!";
    cout << "/n/nWant to play again?(Y/N): ";
    cin >> choice;

    return choice;

}
*/
```

Comment: What number do you enter?

Comment: It doesn't matter so long as it is beteen 2 & 12.

Comment: Why don't you do something like `do{...}while(usernumber < 2 && usernumber > 12)`? It looks much cleaner to me. `while(true)` is often not the greatest thing to see! Otherwise, if you're using `std::cin` somewhere else in the program, there might be a newline in the buffer!

Comment: @IanWise Are you really asking that?

Comment: I have tried do{...} while {..}, also I am not using std::cin elseware.

Comment: If you look at the code it is a less than symbol and a greater than symbol so yes it can be 2 or 12.

Comment: The number that is entered HAS to be between 2 AND 12.

Comment: @thehunter629 that's not right — it *cannot* be 2 or 12

Comment: @FeifanZ: According to the code, 2 and 12 are accepted, not errors.

Comment: [It doesn't](http://ideone.com/Qrf51O) . You might have junk in your input buffer from another part of the program. Please post a complete program that shows the problem.

Comment: but technically 2 is not greater then 2, 2 is 2...

Comment: That is the use of the less than or Equal to sign... =< or =>

Comment: You are calling `user()` twice: in the `do` of `main()` as well as in `Evaluate()`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot elimad.  Using the int userchoice = user(); in main is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Because you call `user()` twice: once from `main`, ignoring the result, and once from  `Evaluate()`.